# How to make Regex choose words separately

Tags: python, regex

So I have this string:

```
sockcooker!~shaz@Rizon-AC7BDF2F.dynamic.dsl.as9105.com !~shaz@ PRIVMSG #Rizon :ohai. New here. registered 10 mins ago, have not got an email. Addy is correct. My email is working fine.
```

I want the regex to find !~shaz@ so I use this r"!.+@" 
but then it finds this

```
!~shaz@Rizon-AC7BDF2F.dynamic.dsl.as9105.com !~shaz@
```

as I remember.I want it to find them as seperate ones and replace them with a certain letter..Any help on this one
and yea if you can give me any good regex tuts for Python I'd be grateful :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, quantifiers are greedy in nature in the sense, they will try to match as much as they can. That is why your regex is matching till the last `@`.

You can use reluctant quantifier (add a `?` after the `+`) to stop at the first `@`:

```
r"!.+?@"
```

Or you can also use `negated` character class, which will automatically stop at the first `@`:

```
r"![^@]+"
```

Choose whatever is easier to understand for you.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an ungreedy match.  There are two ways (and python supports both).  The latter is more flexible:

```
r"![^@]+"
r"!.+?@
```

The `?` makes the `.+` ungreedy, so it will stop at the *first* "@" instead of the last.

Comment: Thanks but too bad someone said it before..But thanks anyways..I'm learning here :D